# How to view a published form?

Tags: 2010, infopath, form

Unbelievably simple question here, but I cannot for the life of me figure it out...

I created an InfoPath form and published it to the SharePoint site following the wizard's instructions. Then when I open SharePoint and browse to the new link, all I am seeing is the /allitems.aspx Standard list view page. Nothing seems to allow me to view the actual form that was published!

How can I view the form, and is there a way I can create a direct link to the display form?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on how you published it. Did you publish it as a content type?

In that case you can see it when you add a new item to a list or library that includes the content type.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "publish as a content type." I just went `File->New->SharePoint List->Design Form` and no where did I see content type. But yes, the form pops up from clicking `Add Item`; so is that the link I need to copy into the site nav for users to go straight to the form?

Comment: By "publish as a content type", I meant that right after you selected to publish it, you have multiple options as to how to do it; one of them is to publish it as a content type. But now I see what you did. And yes, you are correct, if you right-click on "Add new item" and select "Copy shortcut" then that link will take the users straight to the form - you might want to place it as a hyperlink, so it looks more pretty.